# Hiding outsides' pictures parts which are outside the Parent layout?

Tags: image, react-native, layout, flexbox, background-image

Very basically, I got this picture :

[image]

As you can see I have a parent layout, the => `Gradient background`...
I put some text above it, and then, between these two, I'm trying to put a background picture, the bubble chat.

It works pretty well, I just have a small problem, how to hide, not show, the part of the bubble which are not on the layout ?

Wanted result (Well I tried to custom it, but you understand what I want to do...) :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add style `overflow:hidden` to parent element.

This is pure CSS related question and doesn't have much todo with React.

Hopefully this helps, Cheers and happy coding!

Comment: Oh, god, thank you so much, yeah, I always got some problems sometimes concerning the styling... Sometimes too for noob questions lol, but it works now, thank you :) !